# Does "Module: XXX does not have a valid python extension (it will not analyze)." on json file make it unusable?

Tags: python, json, eclipse

I'm new to programming. If I don't use the terms correctly, I apologize in advance.
I'm having an issue trying make my json file work in my py file. My py file is:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint


dataFile =open("Music_Database")
data = json.loads(dataFile)
pprint(data)
dataFile.close()
```

And the error I get from this is:

`OError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'XXX'`

I tried to make my py file work, but I'm out of ideas. Is it because of the "Module: XXX does not have a valid python extension (it will not analyze)." on json file?

Comment: The error message is telling you what the problem is: it can't find the file. Is the "Music_Database" file in the same folder as the script? And what does the other message have to do with your question?

Comment: Is it possible that the file is actually named, say, `Music_Database.db`, and your system is configured to hide extensions, so Finder/Explorer/Nautilus/whatever shows it as just "Music_Database"?

Comment: That's `data = json.load(dataFile)`. The `json.loads` method takes strings; `.load` takes file objects.